# using vba to loop a column of dates into the url line for web query and retrieve an exchange rate table from xe.com/currencytables

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a column of dates (in Excel spreadsheet) and would like to insert these dates into the url line in the web query to generate an exchange rate tables which I would like to put them in the spreadsheets. For example:

Column A
2019-12-09
2019-12-08
2019-12-07

For each of these dates in column A, I would like insert them into the url line: 
Below is a recorded VBA macro using --Get Data, from Web. Then I copy and paste the https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2019-12-10 into the url(pop up window), hit ok and choose table 0 to generate an exchange rate table for the date 2019-12-10. I would like to automate this process and use the dates in Column A. I don't have any experience in power query. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0 (6)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2019-12-08""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Currency code ??"", type text}, {""Currency name ??"", type text}, {""Units per USD"", type number}, {""USD per Unit"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0 (6)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0 (6)]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0__6"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a test I've changed the url:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0 (6)", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=" & Format(DateSerial(2019, 12, 8), "yyyy-mm-dd") & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Currency code"", type text}, {""Currency name"", type text}, {""Units per USD"", type number}, {""USD per Unit"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```

So under format(dateserial()) you can put your variable with date from the cell.

I've also changed **Currency code ??** and **Currency name ??** to **Currency code** and **Currency name** and edited them manually in power query editor in Excel the same way, as there is a problem with those arrows in column names.

If you would like to generate tables for all dates at once, then you have to solve that issue with arrows in the column name (or it is solved already?).

Next step is to make sure that table names are unique and generated automatically.

Last step would be the for loop to go through cells with dates.

---

**UPDATE:**

Ok, below you can find updated code. I've deleted column formatting for problematic columns with special characters. Variables for table name and date are created so now it will be extremely easy to extend that code to create tables for how much historic data you want :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DownloadExchangeRates()
    'Set variables
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wbs As Worksheet

        Dim mydate As Date
        Dim table_name As String
        Dim table_display_name As String

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook

        mydate = DateSerial(2019, 12, 7)
        table_name = "Table " & Format(mydate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        table_display_name = "Table_" & Format(mydate, "yyyy_mm_dd")

    ' Create connection
        wb.Queries.Add _
            Name:=table_name, _
            Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=" & Format(mydate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Units per USD"", type number}, {""USD per Unit"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "    #""Changed Type"""

    'Create new worksheet
        wb.Worksheets.Add
        Set wbs = wb.ActiveSheet
        wbs.Name = "Currency for " & Format(mydate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

        With wbs.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & """" & table_name & """" & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & table_name & "]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = table_display_name
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Szewski, thank you for answering my question. It is not generating the table at all.

Comment: Hi, Please see the update. It is ready to run, test and extend.